# Decode all records from wtmp

Tags: linux, log-files

The Linux log `/var/log/wtmp` according to the man page http://linux.die.net/man/5/wtmp stores "utmp" events for many system events, like logging into it (LOGIN_PROCESS `ut_type`), changing runlevel (RUN_LVL `ut_type`) and other.

There is `last` utility, which parses wtmp and prints who was logged into the system, and when it was rebooted.

Is there tool to display other records from `wtmp` log?

What is the process which writes info into `wtmp` log?

Comment: Have you read [man wtmp](http://linux.die.net/man/5/wtmp) already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several simple perl parsers for wtmp files, like `wtmp.pl` by "Brocade Blue"

http://brocadeblue.blogspot.com/2012/10/perl-script-to-parse-wtmp-logs.html

Full source of `wtmp.pl` with minor typos fixed:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
@type = (
    "Empty", "Run Lvl", "Boot", "New Time", "Old Time", "Init",
    "Login", "Normal",  "Term", "Account"
);
$recs = "";
while (<>) { 
    $recs .= $_;
}
foreach ( split( /(.{384})/s, $recs ) ) {
    next if length($_) == 0 ;
    my ( $type, $pid, $line, $inittab, $user, $host, $t1, $t2, $t3, $t4, $t5 ) =
      $_ =~ /(.{4})(.{4})(.{32})(.{4})(.{32})(.{256})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})/s;
    if ( defined $line && $line =~ /\w/ ) {  ##FILTER
        $line =~ s/\x00+//g;
        $host =~ s/\x00+//g;
        $user =~ s/\x00+//g;
        printf(
            "%s %-8s %-12s %10s %-45s \n",
            scalar( gmtime( unpack( "I4", $t3 ) ) ),
            $type[ unpack( "I4", $type ) ],
            $user,   $line,   $host
        );
    }
}
printf "\n"
```

The script may not work on 64-bit machines. The "384" and long line with `(.{4})` should be fixed for 64-bit environment.

PS: to see really all records, disable the expression in the `if` marked with "`##FILTER`".

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the audit log instead.

Try using `ausearch`, it offers what `utmp` does and more.

Comment: I have no audit log and no ausearch. I have big `wtmp` file, and `last` utility does not print all records from it. I just want to dump all records from existing `wtmp`.